# Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: BigQuery source must be split before being read

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am trying to read from bigquery using Java `BigqueryIO.read` method. but getting below error.

`public POutput expand(PBegin pBegin) {
                final String queryOperation = "select query";
                return pBegin
                        .apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery(queryOperation));
            }`

`2020-06-08 19:32:01.391 ISTError message from worker: java.io.IOException: Failed to start reading from source: org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource$BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter@77f0db34 org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$UnboundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:792) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start(ReadOperation.java:361) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:194) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1320) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:151) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1053) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: BigQuery source must be split before being read org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase.createReader(BigQuerySourceBase.java:173) org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource$BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter$ResidualSource.advance(UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource.java:467) org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource$BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter$ResidualSource.access$300(UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource.java:446) org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource$BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter$Reader.advance(UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource.java:298) org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource$BoundedToUnboundedSourceAdapter$Reader.start(UnboundedReadFromBoundedSource.java:291) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$UnboundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:787) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start(ReadOperation.java:361) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:194) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1320) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:151) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1053) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

Comment: How did you run Dataflow job via `DirectRunner` or `DataflowRunner`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this issue might be connected with missing `tempLocation` pipeline execution [parameter](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#configuring-pipelineoptions-for-execution-on-the-cloud-dataflow-service) when you are using `DataflowRunner` for cloud execution.

According to the documentation:

If **tempLocation** is not specified and **gcpTempLocation** is, **tempLocation** will not be populated.

Since this is just my presumption, I'll also encourage you to inspect native Apache Beam runtime logs to expand the overall issue evidence, as long as  Stackdriver logs don't reflect a full picture of the problem.

There was raised a separate Jira tracker thread [BEAM-9043](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9043), indicating this vaguely outputted error description.

Feel free to append more certain information to you origin question for any further concern or essential updates.

Comment: Thank you for inputs. I have included tempLocation as pipeline option in my run command already, even though issue persists.

Comment: Can you share your pipeline execution parameters then?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, if any error in the query also throws above error. It got solved after the query got corrected.